# window.reload in Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, kotlin

I'm trying to get location.reload() to work in a webView. But I can not load it with a url. I have to load it like this:

```
web_view.loadData(filterString(editor.cleanText), "text/html", "UTF-8")
```

But then the js code dosn't seeem to be able to relaod the webView. filterString removes comments because it says `Unexpected end of input`" otherwise

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem sometimes this won't work:

```
window.open('[YOUR_HTML_PAGE]');
```

by example

```
window.open('index.html');
```

So I use this and this should normally work.

```
window.open('[YOUR_HTML_PAGE]', '_self', false);
```

by example

```
window.open('index.html', '_self', false);
```

Comment: That wont't work for me. I don't want to save files with code. I want to load text.

Comment: Yes but where is the text saved?

Comment: It is not saved at all. It is a String and it absolutely have to stay a String

Comment: So you want to insert that string in html page?

Answer (score 0):

Try window.location.href=page to access. In my case, running fine!